# A humble riddle

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography, history

I am a triumph, a thundering wall;
a goddess, a ruler the grandest of all.

I loom over towers that can touch the skies;
few of world's waters can rival my size.

A landmass colossal, a forebear of kings;
on seven continents my name still rings.

What is my name?

Hint:

> The answer is one word, but to get it you need knowledge about more than one thing.

And another:

> There is less hyperbole in the clues than you'd think.

Comment: Which one or neither

Comment: I see this has been voted down. Feel free to let me know what could be improved.

Comment: Well, you haven't said anything about my response but I am keeping my upvote firm

Comment: It could also be the great wall of China but it doesn't really match with line two

Comment: @Duck I thought the same, hahah

Comment: @Duck I think I wouldn't have led with "wall" for that one ;)

Comment: A volcano, maybe the biggest one on mars; Olympus Mons is three times as tall as iiiiiidk's mount everest

Comment: "There is not much hyperbole"  "A forebear of kings"    A literal ancestor of kings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your name is

> Victoria

I am a triumph, a thundering wall;

> Refers to victory (triumph), and to the Victoria Falls in southern Africa, aka "The Smoke that Thunders"

a goddess, a ruler the grandest of all.

> Victoria is the ancient Roman goddess of Victory, Queen Victoria of the UK could be considered one of the grandest rulers in history, certainly the British Empire was huge during her reign

I loom over towers that can touch the skies;

> Could refer to Victoria Peak, the highest point on the island of Hong Kong (where there is a large city with many towers), otherwise there are many Mount Victorias in the world

few of world's waters can rival my size.

> Refers to Lake Victoria, second largest freshwater lake in the world, biggest in Africa

A landmass colossal, a forebear of kings;

> "Landmass colossal" might refer again to the old British Empire, could also refer to Victoria Land in Antarctica or the state of Victoria in Australia.
> Forebear (aka ancestor) of kings probably refers again to Queen Victoria, who was succeeded by several kings, up until Queen Elizabeth

on seven continents my name still rings.

> Due to the extent of the old British Empire, you can find cities, provinces, states, lakes, mountains, everything named after Queen Victoria on every continent in the world

Edit: Due to the OP's comment, I think "A landmass colossal" may actually refer to

> Victoria Island, 2nd largest island in Canada and 8th largest in the world

Comment: Well done! Fwiw, for the fifth line I was thinking about rot13(n ynetr ynaqznff ragveryl fheebhaqrq ol jngre).

Comment: @jafe given your hint, I've added an edit to my answer

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you are

> Mount Everest, or Chomolungma

I am a triumph, a thundering wall; a goddess, a ruler the grandest of all.

> Largest mountain in the world, and reaches to the clouds. Miyolangsangma is the Tibetan goddess of Giving who is said to live at the top of Everest. Alternatively, it may refer to Everest's Tibetan name, Chomolungma, which means Goddess Mother of Mountains. (@El-Guest for the name)

I loom over towers that can touch the skies; few of world's waters can rival my size.

> As above. Everest is ~29 thousand feet above sea level, and the average ocean depth is ~12 thousand feet below.

A landmass colossal, a forebear of kings; on seven continents my name still rings.

> It's a mountain all right, and has been there a long time. People from all over the world come to Everest to conquer it.

Comment: Great answer! :) I think you're right! Also, I think that the rot13(tbqqrff cneg unf gb qb jvgu gur Gvorgna anzr sbe Rirerfg, Pubzbyhatzn, zrnavat Tbqqrff Zbgure bs Zbhagnvaf).

Comment: Yes, I just added that part- well, the goddess who is said to live there, anyway. Added your part too, because I think it fits better!

Comment: This is a nice fit, but not the intended answer. It's too early for hints, but I have added some tags.

Comment: Mount Everest is two words

Comment: @Duck as is Mother Nature :P

Comment: I know, sorry for that

Comment: @Duck You're fine! We've both got to work towards a new answer with that one-word hint

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is

> "mother nature" because it says goddess and all of the other phrases kind of match. Nature has mountains and other natural landforms. Again, natural landforms. A lot of people call nature mother nature and that is the name too. (going along the riddles lines like @sensoray suggested)

Comment: Make sure to add a `>!` in front of your answer for now on to prevent others from accidentally reading it! This is is a good answer, but can you go into more detail? Identify each part of the riddle and how it specifically applies to your answer?

Comment: It's not this one, although I'm sure some of the clues can be matched. It would be nice to see the reasoning for each individual clue, though.

Comment: I have many more ideas, too. Can you make it a little less broad?

Comment: I'll add a hint if nobody's gotten it in a day or two :)

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are

> Pangaea, a supercontinent that broke up about 175 million years ago.

I am a triumph, a thundering wall;
a goddess, a ruler the grandest of all.

> Pangaea is the largest of continents. Perhaps "thundering wall" refers to the collision of tectonic plates that formed Pangaea. It is named for the goddess Gaea, Mother Earth in Greek mythology.

I loom over towers that can touch the skies;
few of world's waters can rival my size.

> Pangaea covered a huge area and contained many impressive mountain ranges.

A landmass colossal, a forebear of kings;
on seven continents my name still rings.

> I'm not entirely sure of this one but I think it refers that the current seven continents are made up of the pieces of Pangaea after it broke apart. The reference to kings might mean the current seven continents or perhaps Laurasia and Gondwana two later supercontinents that formed in between the time of Pangaea and our current configuration.

Comment: Wow. This fits extremely well, but I'm afraid it's not the intended answer.

Comment: This was my first guess, but I couldn't fit it in perfectly. Glad to see it as an answer though :)

Comment: I was thinking the super continent before pangea

Answer (score 3):

Could the answer be

> **Seven 7**?

`I am a triumph, a thundering wall;`

> The word *triumph* has **seven** letters, and there are [**seven** famous border walls](https://www.history.com/news/7-famous-border-walls)

`a goddess, a ruler the grandest of all.`

> Again, the word *goddess* has **seven** letters, and there are [**seven** olympian goddesses](https://greekgodsandgoddesses.net/) (with six shown in the link, and then [Iris](https://greekgodsandgoddesses.net/goddesses/iris/) as their messenger and Goddess of the Rainbow).

`I loom over towers that can touch the skies;`

> Unsure about this one. But...

> ...it could possibly refer to the [**seven** heavens](http://www.archangels-and-angels.com/misc/seven_heavens.html) which talks about "the seven layers of the sky" and the "seven planets in our solar system". However, science reveals that there are five layers of the atmosphere (sky); and there are 9 planets in our solar system thus far, though there may be [12 planets](https://www.universetoday.com/472/officials-propose-12-planets-in-the-solar-system/). 
>  
>  Vesta was a planet, then reclassified as an asteroid; Eris is now classified as the most massive *dwarf* planet in our solar system (thus far), though that is not an actual planet, just like Pluto; but we do have the so-called [Planet Nine](https://www.space.com/16080-solar-system-planets.html) (and then "the mysterious, mythical Nibiru (Planet X) which apparently 'destroyed life on the red planet, Mars'..." but let's not get into that).

`few of world's waters can rival my size.`

> The [**seven** seas](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-7733,00.html), whatever they were, really. There are many references with different kinds of seas, but there are [**seven** main oceans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Seas). 
>  <sub>In the former link, the term "yesteryear" means "last year".</sub>

`A landmass colossal, a forebear of kings;`

> The [**seven** wonders of the ancient world](https://www.wonders-of-the-world.net/Seven/List-of-the-seven-wonders-of-the-ancient-world.php) and/or the [**seven** wonders of the modern world](https://www.wonders-of-the-world.net/Seven/List-of-the-seven-wonders-of-the-modern-world.php).

`on seven continents, my name still rings.`

> The [**seven** continents](https://www.whatarethe7continents.com/) and how in the centre of all of them, there is the [**Ring** of Fire](https://www.cnn.com/2017/09/08/world/ring-of-fire-explainer/index.html). (There is some debate that there should be [eight continents](https://www.bustle.com/p/earth-might-actually-have-8-continents-the-reason-why-is-mind-boggling-39344), but that debate is pretty much comparable to the debate on whether or not Pluto is a planet.)

`What is my name?`

> **Seven**?

---

**Title:**

`A humble riddle`

> The [**Seven** Virtues](http://changingminds.org/explanations/values/seven_virtues.htm), whichever set you probably referred to in the title (although Aristotle argues that there are twelve, pursuant to his 'Golden Mean' of actions regarding *Nicomachean Ethics*.)

---

<sub>The links I chose in my answer are just the simplest links with not as much information compared to other sites, because at the end of the day, this is just a riddle we are talking about.</sub>

Comment: interesting answer

Comment: Nice thought process, but I'm looking for something that fits the clues in a more literal sense.

Comment: The outside-the-box thinking on this one! Very cool answer